# PyQt5 : Get values from multiple QTextEdit obtained through loop

Tags: python, for-loop, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

Currently working on a user interface through PyQt5, I'm trying to create TextEdit windows depending on the number selected from a Combobox (displayed in MainWindow).
This part is working (cf. first code below) however when I'm trying to get values (cf. second code) from text boxes created in the process, I only managed to get the value from the last text box.

Do you have any idea to get all of them?

Thanks in advance,

```
#Create text windows depending on number selected from a combo box

class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, SecondWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SecondWindow.setObjectName("SecondWindow")
        SecondWindow.resize(500, 720)

        self.grid_layout = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        self.grid_layout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 250, 1000))
        self.grid_layout.setObjectName("grid_layout")

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.grid_layout)
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.grid.setObjectName('grid')

        for i in range(1, int_nb_cond+1):

            self.enter_nbcond = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.grid_layout)
            self.enter_nbcond.setMaximumHeight(26)
            self.enter_nbcond.setObjectName("enter_nbcond")
            self.enter_nbcond.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SecondWindow", f"Name condition {i}:"))
            self.enter_nbcond.resize(5,5)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.enter_nbcond, i, 0)
```

```
#Get values from text edit windows

    def ent(self):
        print(self.enter_nbcond.toPlainText())
```

Comment: `self.enter_nbcond` gets overwritten every time the loop iterates, so creating it as instance attribute is completely pointless. Create a list as an instance attribute, and add the widget instances to it in the loop. Also, don't edit pyuic files, but instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: standard rule: if you run `for`-loop then you have to keep results/items on `list`

Comment: Another note: the purpose of layout managers is, as the name suggests, to *manage* the layout. When a widget is added to layout, setting its geometry (including calling `resize()`) is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Standard rule: if you run `for`-loop then you have to keep results/items on `list`

---

Before loop you have to create list and inside loop you use `.append()` to keep widgets `QTextEdit` on this list.

```
# --- before loop ---

self.enter_nbcond = []

# --- loop ---

for i in range(1, int_nb_cond+1):

    item = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.grid_layout)
    item.setMaximumHeight(26)
    item.setObjectName("enter_nbcond")
    item.setPlaceholderText(_translate("SecondWindow", f"Name condition {i}:"))
    item.resize(5,5)

    self.grid.addWidget(item, i, 0)

    self.enter_nbcond.append(item)
```

And later you have to use `for`-loop to get all values

```
def ent(self):
    for item in self.enter_nbcond:
        print(item.toPlainText())
```